# How can I hold a WeakReference<Action> to a method of an instance until the instance is collected?

Tags: c#, weak-references

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inst = new SomeClass();
        var weakRef = new WeakReference<Action>(inst.DoSomething);
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine($"inst is alive = {inst != null} : weakRef.Target is alive = {weakRef.TryGetTarget(out Action callback)}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

The output shows that `inst` is not null, but the reference that `WeakReference<Action>` points to is. I expect this is because a new Action is created that points to the instance method, rather than storing a reference to the instance's method itself.

How can I hold a weak reference to a method of an object instance for the duration that the instance is not yet garbage collected?

Comment: You are holding the `inst` reference, but noone is holding the auto generated `Action` object by the syntactic sugar you wrote. Try it by explicit using a variable of type `Action`.

Comment: @Progman I realised the problem and changed the question just before you answered.

Comment: What happens when you save the Action in a variable before the `GC.Collect();` call? It shouldn't be claimed when you have an active reference to the Action object.

Comment: Save `Action` to the `SomeClass` field. That way `Action` can not be collected before `SomeClass`. If modifying `SomeClass` is not possible, then you can use [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2) class.

Comment: @PetSerAl You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need that `Action` instance would not be collected before `SomeClass` instance, then you need to add reference from `SomeClass` instance to `Action` instance. It can be instance field of `SomeClass` that point to `Action` instance, but if you can not alter `SomeClass` definition, than you can use [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2) class to attach field dynamically.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default)]
public class SomeClass {
    public void DoSomething() { }
}
public static class DelegateKeeper {
    private static ConditionalWeakTable<object, List<Delegate>> cwt = new ConditionalWeakTable<object, List<Delegate>>();
    public static void KeepAlive(Delegate d) => cwt.GetOrCreateValue(d?.Target ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(d))).Add(d);
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        SomeClass inst = new SomeClass();
        Action a1 = inst.DoSomething;
        DelegateKeeper.KeepAlive(a1);
        Action a2 = inst.DoSomething;
        WeakReference<SomeClass> winst = new WeakReference<SomeClass>(inst);
        WeakReference<Action> wa1 = new WeakReference<Action>(a1);
        WeakReference<Action> wa2 = new WeakReference<Action>(a2);
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine($"{winst.TryGetTarget(out _),5}:{wa1.TryGetTarget(out _),5}:{wa2.TryGetTarget(out _),5}");
        GC.KeepAlive(a1);
        GC.KeepAlive(a2);
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine($"{winst.TryGetTarget(out _),5}:{wa1.TryGetTarget(out _),5}:{wa2.TryGetTarget(out _),5}");
        GC.KeepAlive(inst);
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine($"{winst.TryGetTarget(out _),5}:{wa1.TryGetTarget(out _),5}:{wa2.TryGetTarget(out _),5}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 True: True: True
 True: True:False
False:False:False
```

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##1VTBjtowEL3zFdaqh0TaWlqkXhYWFIVqD91tqwV1D1VVOc6QdevYyB5DEeLbWTsQSGiD1Fvrkz3z/PzmzSTcvuXawG7nrFAFma4tQjnoNU801VICR6GVpfegwAh@hpgIVihtUXB7lnlyCkUJnqNcCAlmCmYpOHjYV2YtlJlc35IJZK4oWCYhOm0TRCMyh0D3MU/6qHOw/jhnTmL8rbdwmRSccOmpyFSXkFa7TY/4dUgutcjJRIcsvniOKCYbsu1t68sWGR45JiChYAgfABZgaiIjlj5WI1OtchHMYPIZ2M9Z0DrU2Q/v0DV5EBaHNctoRPgKyR1RsPqra1E8aJZweLiqJChLpFgGp/ZwksfkrnrJNwc/mdSAj35h0kGUj@mMmQKQjMcEX4xeVVoSU7gSFH50Ur7/xWERdEWKlaDnUR7HMU3y3G8G3qaWP5@NLgwrD8Y0dT0yoYK1VSKsUzuEsrUJx2BdYVhJNVqE3XhQwNJGt06odmvoyQd28weu/kWu0IAnmIMBxWF4FDUiq4bWLlAUMHEX2V6AZ6rK@Z3nkG@r7qLoX6boNyju0/ozbVrrh85qCfTZCIQHoSB6c7WpiqQzs/bjsp@OSDsk3@Prd9vbjRd@IdfvyF21pXR0p535H@Sf9fofkel/X7vdKw)

In `DelegateKeeper` class I use `List<Delegate>` as dependent object type, so you can keep multiple delegates per one class instance. I use [`Delegate.Target`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.delegate.target) as key to the table, so you do not need to pass instance separately. This would not work with anonymous methods, since them likely to have compiler generated closure class in `Target` property. `GetOrCreateValue` get value bound to key or create new one using default constructor and add it to table automatically.

Comment: I've got to admit, it took me *way* longer than I expected to understand what is going on with `DelegateKeeper`.  I think I've finally got it now, but would you mind explaining it in a bit more detail?  I think it will make this a much better answer.

Comment: Wait, after thinking about this more, and digging more in to the MSDN link, don't you need to add the result of `cwt.GetOrCreateValue` to `cwt` with `cwt.Add`? `GetOrCreateValue` doesn't say that it automatically adds and tracks the value by the key.  This existing `Add` that you have just adds the delegate to the `List`, not `cwt`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2.getorcreatevalue): If the key does not exist in the table, the method invokes the default constructor of the class that represents the table's value to create **a value that is bound to the specified key.**

Comment: Source: [`GetOrCreateValue`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/ConditionalWeakTable.cs,274): Helper method to call GetValue without passing a creation delegate. [`GetValue`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/ConditionalWeakTable.cs,214): Atomically tests if key exists in table. If so, returns corresponding value. If not, invokes createValueCallback() passing it the key. **The returned value is bound to the key in the table** and returned as the result of GetValue().

Comment: I think your example code overcomplicates your answer, but `ConditionalWeakTable` looks like what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Creating an `Action` instance from a MethodGroup creates an instance that isn't attached in any way to the instance of the class that the method is a member of.  That means that there is nothing keeping your `Action` rooted, and the GC will happily collect it.

If you store a reference to the `Action` as a member of the class, it will become rooted to the lifetime of that instance, preventing it from being collected as long as that instance is alive.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        DoSomething = this.DoSomething_Internal ;
    }

    public Action DoSomething { get; } 

    private void DoSomething_Internal() { }
}
```

Note: I made the original `DoSomething` private, and renamed it to `DoSomething_Internal`, replacing the old `DoSomething` with a readonly property in order to keep the class signature as close as possible to your original class.  You don't need to follow this pattern exactly, any reference to the `Action` stored in the class, including in a normal field, will do. Though you will still have to expose that reference somehow if you actually want to be able to use it.

You can test it like this:

```
var inst = new SomeClass();
var weakRef = new WeakReference<Action>(inst.DoSomething);

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); // You should do this after forcing a GC, just in case there is still GC work being done in the background.

Console.WriteLine($"inst is alive = {inst != null} : weakRef.Target is alive = {weakRef.TryGetTarget(out Action callback1)}");

// These next 2 lines discard local variables, as Hans points out in the comments,  
// DO NOT do this in production code.  Please read the link he posted for more details.
inst = null; // discard the class instance
callback1 = null; // discard the temporary Action instance from TryGetTarget, otherwise it will act as a GC Root, preventing it from being collected later.

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Console.WriteLine($"inst is alive = {inst != null} : weakRef.Target is alive = {weakRef.TryGetTarget(out Action callback2)}");
```

Which produces the following output:

> inst is alive = True : weakRef.Target is alive = True
>   inst is alive = False : weakRef.Target is alive = False

Comment: Don't set these object references to null please.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034

Comment: @HansPassant That's some fascinating insight in to the GC, thank you!  I was using the test code in LINQPad, and setting those instances to `null` seemed the easiest way to prove that the `Action` was collected when the class instance was. I would never advocate using that pattern in "real" code.  Though that does make me realize that I should probably be calling `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` after `GC.Collect`, just for extra safety.

Comment: I need to be able to implement something that does not require me to alter `SomeClass`